# Доменная авторизация на SQL сервере с помощью IIS + PHP

Tags: php, sql, iis

Есть сервер IIS с установленным php. К нему могут подключаться пользователи под своим доменными учетками. На этом шаге проблем нет, подключенного пользователя проверяю с помощью
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];

Проблема в том, что из этого скрипта мне нужно соединиться с SQL-сервером (2008), на котором поддерживается только доменная авторизация.
Тестил через IE 10, IE 11 и EDGE - всё работает.
В остальных браузерах ловлю ошибку NT AUTHORITY\АНОНИМНЫЙ ВХОД. Однако, если я хотя бы раз обновлю страницу в IE или EDGE и установлю соединение, то и в остальных всё заработает, правда, ненадолго и потом снова получаю вышеуказанную ошибку.
Смотрел эту тему - https://www.sql.ru/forum/1177558/ms-sql-server-php-iis-nastroyka-win-autentifikacii?hl=authority
Увы, но не помогло.

Comment: 1) $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; - легко подделать(так авторизацию не делают)
2) Никто, из браузеров, кроме IE (и его наследников) не умеют в прозрачную LDAP авторизацию на достаточном для SQL сервера уровне. Т.е. подключаясь через IE вы просто делаете сессию(настоящую LDAP авторизацию), и пока жива ваша сессия - остальные браузеры могут работать, как только сессия истекает - токены устаревают и SQL вам законно пишет что вы не авторизованы. **внимательно посмотрите первый пункт**

Comment: Как же тогда лучше организовать авторизацию? SQL сервер будет работать только с виндовой авторизацией, переводить его в смешанный режим, увы, нельзя.